# How can I linearize the following equation (Bergman model)?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, nonlinear-dynamics

I have to linearize the following equation so that I can use the Laplace transform and get the transfer function for the system. The equation is:
$$\frac{dG(t)}{dt}=-p_1 G(t)-p_2 X(t)G(t)+ ....$$
$p_1$ and $p_2$ are problem parameters and $G(t)$ and $X(t)$ are the variables of the problem. I linearize $X(t)G(t)$ using the following Taylor approximation at a steady state
$$X(t)G(t)\approx X_sG_s+\frac{\partial (X(t)G(t))}{\partial X(t)}|_s (X(t)-X_s)+\frac{\partial (X(t)G(t))}{\partial G(t)}|_s (G(t)-G_s)+...$$
Which yields
$$X(t)G(t)\approx X_sG_s+G_s (X(t)-X_s)+X_s(G(t)-G_s)+..$$
Do you think that this is acceptable or should I instead take the partial derivatives with respect to time t?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Math.SE: your equation is already linear, since if $G_1(t)$ and $G_2(t)$ are solutions so $\alpha G_1(t)+\beta G_1(t)$ with $\alpha, \beta\in\Bbb R$ is. More than a linearization, it seems that your aim is to find a constant coefficient approximation to your former equation. In this context, taking the partial derivative respect to time does not improve your approximation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn’t specify that this is a system of DE and $X(t)$ is also a state variable